# Add audio and watermark in a video with one command using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, android, watermark

I want add audio and a watermark to a video with only one command. Currently I added the watermark first using the below command:

> `String[] cmd={"-i",videoPath,"-ignore_loop","0","-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/heart.gif","-filter_complex","{1:v]format=yuva444p,scale="+1280+":"+-1+",setsar=1,rotate="+angle+":c=black@0:ow=rotw("+angle+"):oh=roth("+angle+") [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay="+0+":0:shortest=1","-codec:a","copy","-y","/storage/emulated/0/Movies/watermarker_center14.mp4"};`

then add audio into the video using the below command:

> `String[] cmd1={"-i",videopath,"-i",audiopath,"-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-map","0:v:0","-map","1:a:0","-shortest",output};`

It takes a long time to execute the command and generate the final video.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`String[] cmd={"-i",videoPath,"-ignore_loop","0","-i","/storage/emulated/0/Download/heart.gif","-i",audiopath,"-filter_complex","{1:v]format=yuva444p,scale="+1280+":"+-1+",setsar=1,rotate="+angle+":c=black@0:ow=rotw("+angle+"):oh=roth("+angle+") [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay="+0+":0:shortest=1[v]","-map","'[v]'","-map","2:a:0","-c:a","aac","-shortest","-y","/storage/emulated/0/Movies/watermarker_center14.mp4"};`